# Regular expression with css

Tags: css

I have ids with this pattern

product0, product1, product2, product3...

I need to write a css selector to identify all these elements

I tried the below selector but does not work

```
$('product[0-9]')
```

Comment: That's not a CSS selector; that's a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to

```
[id^="product"] {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select all elements that start with a given ID...

`$("[id^='product']")`

This will give you all elements that have an ID that starts with the value 'product', then you could just do some post check on each one found to make sure they have a valid number.